# Why does boost deadline_timer used as timeout for async_connect not work on unix?

Tags: c++, unix, boost, asio, deadline-timer

I have a program that uses boost asio to connect to 3 TCP sockets asynchronously using a `deadline_timer` as a connect timeout. On windows everything works as expected. The connection times out after 5 seconds. However, on Unix(Ubuntu on WSL, Linux Mint VM, macOS) the connectDeadline never fires. The async_connect operation just runs on forever. Why does this not work and how can I make this work on Unix as well?

Code:
Note: connect is called from the main thread (which is also a GUI thread).

```
#include "NetManager.h"

NetManager::NetManager(NetManagerListener& listener) :  listener(listener),
connectDeadline(io),
                                                        socket1(io),
                                                        socket2(io),
                                                        socket3(io),
                                                        asioThread(&NetManager::handleAsioOperations, this){

}
NetManager::~NetManager() {
    running = false;
    io.stop();
    asioThread.join();
}

void NetManager::connect(){
    connectCounter = 0;
    hasHandledConnectError = false;
    socket1.async_connect(
            tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(IP_STRING), PORT_1),
            boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnect, this, _1));
    socket2.async_connect(
            tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(IP_STRING), PORT_2),
            boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnect, this, _1));
    socket3.async_connect(
            tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(IP_STRING), PORT_3),
            boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnect, this, _1));
    connectDeadline.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(CONNECT_TIMEOUT));
    connectDeadline.async_wait(boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnectTimeout, this, _1));
}

void NetManager::disconnect(){
    //NOTE: Close also cancels incomplete async operations
    socket1.close();
    socket2.close();
    socket3.close();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// ASIO Handlers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void NetManager::handleAsioOperations(){
    while(running){
        io.run(); // Run any async operations
    }
}

void NetManager::handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
    // When connections are canceled the handler is called with operation_aborted. No need to respond to that.
    if(ec && ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted && !hasHandledConnectError){
        hasHandledConnectError = true; // Likely to be 3 repeated errors. Make sure to only handle the first one
        cerr << "Connect Failed: " << ec.message() << endl;
        connectDeadline.cancel(); // Don't fire the timeout
        disconnect(); // Disconnect any already connected sockets
        connectedToRobot = false;
        listener.onConnect(false);
    }else if (!ec){
        connectCounter++;
    }

    if(connectCounter == 3){
        cout << "Successful connect" << endl;
        connectDeadline.cancel(); // Don't fire the timeout
        connectedToRobot = true;
        listener.onConnect(true);
    }
}

void NetManager::handleConnectTimeout(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
    if(ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted){
        cerr << "Connect timed out." << endl;
        disconnect(); // Disconnect any already connected sockets
        connectedToRobot = false;
        listener.onConnect(false);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Confusingly, this works fine on Unix OSes:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>                                                                                                                    
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>                                                                                                     
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                          
#include <thread>                                                                                                                            

using namespace boost::asio;                                                                                                                 
using namespace boost::asio::ip;                                                                                                             

int main(){                                                                                                                                  
        io_service io;                                                                                                                       
        deadline_timer timer1(io);                                                                                                           
        tcp::socket sock(io);                                                                                                                

        timer1.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));                                                                              
        sock.async_connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.50.30.1"), 8090), [](const boost::system::error_code &ec){
                std::cout << "SocketError: " << ec.message() << std::endl;                                                                   
        });                                                                                                                                  
        timer1.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec){                                                                          
                std::cout << "First timer" << std::endl;                                                                                     
                sock.close();                                                                                                                
        });                                                                                                                                  
        std::thread worker([&](){                                                                                                            
                while(true){                                                                                                                 
                        io.run();                                                                                                            
                }                                                                                                                            
        });                                                                                                                                  
        worker.detach();                                                                                                                     
        while(true){} // Simulate the unavailable main (GUI) thread                                                                          
}
```

Output:

```
First timer
SocketError: Operation canceled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::io_service::run` stops if there is no work. You should not be calling it in a loop like this because as the documentation state:

> A normal exit from the run() function implies that the io_service
>   object is stopped (the stopped() function returns true). Subsequent
>   calls to run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() will return
>   immediately unless there is a prior call to reset().

You don't show when you call connect() in your first example, I assume it is not long after, so the fact that it works or not comes down to how fast the thread is launched and the `run()` call executed.

You can circumvent this behavior by using `boost::io_service::work` which will prevent the `io_service` from running out of work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer after testing many different scenarios both on Ubuntu and Windows. It turns out that using a thread to continuously call `io_service::run` does not work on Unix OSes if the thread calling `io_service.run` is created before the async tasks (`async_wait`, `async_connect`) are started. The second example I posted breaks (on unix not windows) if the worker thread is created before the calls to `async_connect` and `async_wait`. I have just modified my NetManger class to remove the always running thread.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

class NetManager{
private:
    io_service io;
    tcp::socket socket1, socket2, socket3;
    deadline_timer connectDeadline;
    int connectCounter = 0;

    void handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
        if(ec){
            std::cout << "Connect error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            connectDeadline.cancel();
            disconnect();
        }else
            connectCounter++;
        if(connectCounter == 3)
            std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;

    }
    void handleConnectTimeout(const boost::system::error_code &ec){
        std::cout << "Timeout fired." << std::endl;
        disconnect();
    }
public:
    void connect(){
        connectCounter = 0;
        connectDeadline.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        socket1.async_connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.50.30.1"), 8090), boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnect, this, _1));
        socket2.async_connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.50.30.1"), 8091), boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnect, this, _1));
        socket3.async_connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.50.30.1"), 8092), boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnect, this, _1));
        connectDeadline.async_wait(boost::bind(&NetManager::handleConnectTimeout, this, _1));
        std::thread([&]{io.run();}).detach(); // Run the async operations on a separate thread
    }
    void disconnect(){
        socket1.close();
        socket2.close();
        socket3.close();
    }
    NetManager(): connectDeadline(io),
                  socket1(io),
                  socket2(io),
                  socket3(io){

    }
    ~NetManager(){
        io.stop();
    }
};

int main(){
    NetManager manager;
    manager.connect();
    std::cout << "Trying to connect..." << std::endl;
    while(true); // Simulate the busy main (GUI) thread.
}
```